# javascript sub function event assigment

Tags: javascript, html

There is a js code for page onload. 
It contans function (will name it submain). 
There is an other function otside page load section (ordinary). 
I need to assign onclick event to some control (in this example it is div) with cgi code (inside tag by command onclick=... like it is done for #tag1).

Code of submain is already "known" (cause it is inside document load function) and **can be assigned** with jquery, but I can't find the way to do it with onclick.

Any thought about it?

```js
//this section will execute at document load
$(document).ready(function() {

  //this function will be known
  function submain() {
    alert('submain');
  }
  //assign click event to tag2
  $('#tag2').on('click', function(sender) {
    submain()
  });

})

//function outside executed onload block
function ordinary() {
  alert('ordinary');
}
```

```css
div {
  cursor: pointer;
}

div:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  Assigments test:<br><br>
  <!-- we can point to js function not executed yet by onclick event -->
  <div id="tag1" onclick="ordinary()">ordinary</div><br>

  <!-- we can point to js subfunction function already executed (known) by jquery (see above) -->
  <div id="tag2">jquery submain</div><br>

  <!-- we can not point to js subfunction not executed by onclick event -->
  <div id="tag3" onclick="submain()">submain onclick inline 1</div><br>

  <!-- we can not point to js subfunction not executed by onclick event with function (copy paste like from debug tools firefox debug tools) -->
  <div id="tag3" onclick="(function(){submain()})">submain onclick inline 2</div><br>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`submain` is defined inside the anonymous function you pass to `ready`. It is **scoped** to that function. It is not a global. It is not accessible from the `onclick` attribute because it is out of scope.

While you could make it a global, `onclick` attributes (and globals for that matter) come with a bunch of problems, so you should bind it with JavaScript instead. It's the preferred method and you have already done it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Static assigment will be easy, but...
Fix it with dynamic assigment like following:

on click load  with jquery assigment onclick to control and control itself.
Like here below.

html:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
    div{
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    div:hover {
        text-decoration:underline;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#add_more').on('click', function(sender) {
$.ajax({
    url: "/cgi-bin/tst.py",
})
.done(function( data ) {
    $("#content").html(data);
});
});
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="add_more">load more code</div>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

python (cgi):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

print("Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8")
print()


a='''
<script>
function do_best() {
alert('hope that work')
}

$('#some').on('click', function (sender) {
    do_best()
});
</script>
<div id='some'>make it possible</div>
'''

print(a)
```

Work fine.